# What does "they could not quite picture to themselves" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I try to expand my vocabulary by reading books, but always find difficult sentences like this one:

> And this appeared very strange to most of my Western friends. **They could not quite picture to themselves** how a man of Western birth and upbringing could have so fully, and apparently with no mental reservations what-ever, identified himself with the Muslim world[.]

[*The Road To Mecca*, by Muhammad Asad](https://books.google.com/books?id=xuC1AwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT8&ots=IJoJoW3Kj-&dq=%22they%20could%20not%20quite%20picture%20to%20themselves%20how%20a%20man%20of%20western%20birth%22&pg=PT8#v=onepage&q=%22they%20could%20not%20quite%20picture%20to%20themselves%20how%20a%20man%20of%20western%20birth%22&f=false)

Comment: What is this quote from? Is there a word missing after *mental*?

Comment: @TRiG There are actually a few omitted words.  I've proposed an edit that completes the quote and adds a link to the source.

Answer (score 2):

"They couldn't (quite) imagine [...]" is synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot ***picture*** something, it means you cannot imagine or get an idea about how it happens.

Out of a few meanings of the verb *[picture](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/picture?showCookiePolicy=true)*, one is...

> *visualize or imagine*

Here, the author describes that the western friends cannot get an idea about how a man ...